# Fingerprint scanner "device claimed by other process"

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have seen plenty of people with their system not recognizing their finger print scanner, but that's not what's happening here. My system recognizes my scanner and lets me get one swipe in trying to set up finger print login, then it fails and gives me the following message:

Failed to claim fingerprint device ElanTech Fingerprint Sensor: the device is already claimed by another process

I have run updates and restarted but the problem persists. I looked at the running processes but nothing had any reason to be using the fingerprint scanner. I checked the list of supported fingerprint scanners and this one seems to be on it, its the one that comes installed in the Dell Inspiron 7370.

Has anyone had this issue before? I can post a screenshot of the processes if anyone thinks that will help.

edit: currently running ubuntu 22.04, but the fingerprint scanner had similar problems without the error message when running 20.04

edit 2: based on a similar question I was able to check and my scanner's ID (ID 04f3:0c01 Elan Microelectronics Corp.) IS on the list of supported scanners.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please EDIT the question and add this info.